# How do you test an application that involves multiple steps to reach a particular stage for testing?

Tags: testing, node.js

I am currently writing a game. I am having a little trouble with testing it.

A simple example involves something like this:

1. Everybody joins the game
2. Everyone presses ready. once everyone has pressed ready. game starts
3. Something crazy happens

I do not have any trouble testing 1 and 2. However, I realize in order to test three, I have to call 1 and then 2. Subsequently testing the next item according to game flow will also involve testing 1, 2 and 3 altogether.

What kind of testing is this? I know for sure this is not unit testing. It sounds a bit like integration testing.

What is the correct way to test an application like this?

PS I am writing this app on nodejs. What would be a good framework for me to use that allows me to do something like this? (I am currently using nodeunit and it doesn't really allow me to call the previous test cases without throwing me errors).

Answer (score 1):

First unit test it. The difficulty in unit testing is telling you to separate responsibilities. Your describing a state. Implement using the state pattern. Better code and functionality that may or may not be used in any state (e.g. everybody has pressed ready ... game state is 'started') be fully independently tested. So you end up with nice functional blocks.

Now ... once your 'state engine' and states are tested you want to wire them up. This is integration testing (assuming your not testing the whole app). The intent of the integration test is to test the wiring of a sub-system, not all the functionality, and not all the app.

Comment: Ok that clears up that I definitely do NOT want to do integration testing because it does NOT test what I want. I am not integration subsystems - I am merely continuously calling tests cases within tests to get to the right state for testing.

Comment: So putting the integration testing to one side. There is no need to call tests cases within tests if your using the state pattern. I think your calling tests within tests to walk to code to a state. I think this will become difficult to maintain. With the state pattern each state is its own class. In your case you have at least three states: "Joining", "Starting", "Something Crazy happens". You can unit test that "Starting" transitions to "Something Crazy happens" and you can unit test crazy stuff.